# Lock command discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a lock command here is my code:

```
module.exports = {
  name: "lock",
  description: "Lock",
  async run(client, message, args) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')
    function lock(message) {
      let channel = message.channel;
      let roles = message.guild.roles;
      let testRole = roles.find('Verified');
      channel.overwritePermissions(
        testRole, {
          'SEND_MESSAGES': false
        },
        'Competitive has Ended'
      )
      lock(message).catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
    message.channel.send('Channel Locked')
  }
}
```

However, on running this code I get no response from the bot neither does it carry out the function. I don't get any error too. Can toy help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You define a function `lock`, but you call it in the wrong place. You try to call the lock function within the function itself, which won't work. If you change your code to the following it should work:

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')
function lock(message) {
  let channel = message.channel;
  let roles = message.guild.roles;
  let testRole = roles.find('Verified');
  channel.overwritePermissions(
    testRole, {
      'SEND_MESSAGES': false
    },
    'Competitive has Ended'
  )
}
lock(message).catch(error => console.log(error));
message.channel.send('Channel Locked')
```